# Looking for Lawvere's "Closed categories and biclosed bicategories" lecture notes

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, 2-categories

The [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+bicategory) on closed bicategories reads

> Closed bicategories were introduced by Lawvere in unpublished lecture notes Closed categories and biclosed bicategories (1971).

This work has also been cited in e.g.

> Ross Street, *Enriched categories and cohomology with author commentary*. Originally published as: Enriched categories and cohomology, Quaestiones Mathematicae, 6 (1983), 265-283, used by permission. 2000 MSC: 18D20, 18D30. Republished in: Reprints in Theory and Applications of Categories, No. 14 (2005), pp 1-18

as

> [12] F. W. Lawvere (1971). Closed categories and biclosed bicategories. Mathematics
> Institute Aarhus Universitet, Aarhus. handwritten lecture notes

There are also a few other works citing it (see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Closed+categories+and+biclosed+bicategories%22+%281971%29.)). It's also <s>not</s> (update: now it is) listed in the GitHub repository for [The collected works of F. W. Lawvere](https://github.com/mattearnshaw/lawvere), and I haven't been able to find a copy online.

Does anyone have a copy of these notes?

Comment: Since Street cites the work in several of his papers, you could ask him whether he would be willing to scan it and make it publicly available?

Comment: @varkor Oh, that's a good idea! I'll email him.